# Implementing RSA unit for 128bits-C++

Tags: c++, rsa

I am able to work this out for small numbers. Encryption works fine for even big numbers. However, there is some issue with the decryption unit. Can someone help me out?

```
main()
{
   //__uint128_t secret=((__uint128_t)3502532219136638976) <<64 |1161929539123609600; 
   //__uint128_t pvtkey=((__uint128_t)14605469131018042215) <<64 |1281687108645159073;
   //__uint128_t n=((__uint128_t)16156614574048939703) <<64| 17372945349702060311;

   decrypt(1434,1293,2491);
}




__uint128_t decrypt(__uint128_t secret,__uint128_t pvtkey,__uint128_t n)
{
   cout<< "Decrypting..."<<"\n";


   __uint128_t imsg_copy2=pvtkey;
    uint64_t imsg64_lo2,imsg64_hi2;
    imsg64_lo2=imsg_copy2;
    imsg_copy2=imsg_copy2>>64;
    imsg64_hi2=imsg_copy2;
    cout << "Pvt key recvd here:"<<imsg64_lo2<<"\n";
    cout << "Pvt key recvd here  hi:"<<imsg64_hi2<<"\n";
    __uint128_t r=1;
    int ctr=0;
    while(1)
     {
       if(((__uint128_t)pvtkey)%2==1)
          {r=(((__uint128_t)r)*((__uint128_t)secret))%((__uint128_t)n);
           cout<<" r:" << r << "\n" ;
          }
     //      cout <<"Dividing";
      pvtkey=((__uint128_t)pvtkey)/2;
      cout << "r:";
      printf_128(r);
      cout << ctr << "\n";

      if(pvtkey==0)
            break;
      cout<<"secret:";
      secret=(((__uint128_t)secret)*((__uint128_t)secret)%((__uint128_t)n));
      printf_128(secret);
      ctr++;

      cout << "Decryption inside function_lo:"<<"\n";
      printf_128(r);
      return ((__uint128_t)r);
     }


 void printf_128(__uint128_t v)
 {

              __uint128_t imsg_copy=v;
              uint64_t imsg64_lo,imsg64_hi;
              imsg64_lo=imsg_copy;
              imsg_copy=imsg_copy>>64;
              imsg64_hi=imsg_copy;
              cout  <<imsg64_hi<<imsg64_lo<<"\n";

  }
```

So, when I run this function for smaller numbers, the decryption unit works fine. However, when i do this for large public keys, all the values get set to 0.Can someone help ?

Comment: All the values get set to 0? That seems really easy to track down with some breakpoints.

Comment: Most, if not all, of these (__uint128_t) casts seem unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You multiply two 128-bit number, which will give a 128-bit number in your code - but you need the full result (a 256-bit number) and then compute the result mod n.